# How does starred expression works when using with find_element() method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
def enter_text_textbox(self, locator, text):
    ele = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
    try:
        logging.info("# Entering text in Textbox.")
        ele.clear()
        ele.send_keys(text)
        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Here is a method enter_text_textbox which accepts locator and some text as parameters.
I passed locator as something like this:
        self.email_field = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']")

When I tried to get into this(self.driver.find_element(*locator)) method, it displayed[image]

As from the image the methods contains parameters of ID only.

By running the test script(not displayed here), it worked perfectly fine.
I want to know how does this method know if this locator is made by XPATH or ID or CSS i.e. How the starred expression works?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.driver.find_element(*locator)
```

unpacks into positional arguments. So `locator[0]` *has* to be xpath, and `locator[1]` has to be the other text argument (ID or CSS apparently)

It's equivalent (when `locator` has the proper number of arguments) to:

```
self.driver.find_element(locator[0],locator[1])
```

note:

- Passing parameters in the wrong order will fail.
- Passing not enough or too many parameters will also fail.

Since this isn't a variable argument function, this is bad practice & very unclear.

Comment: While this might be crystal clear for someone, can you please explain *why* this seem to be a bad practice and *what* exactly is unclear to you? Note that separating locators from code is *good practice* when you use [Page Object pattern](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-object-classes) and your suggestions might mislead OP

Comment: This appears to me as bad practice in general as positional arguments in a method with 2 arguments should be separate. But I'm not a selenium specialist so my opinion is maybe wrong in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The image you are showing shows PyCharm telling you what the method uses by default. If you were to just call `find_element()` it would use `By.ID` as the `by` value and `None` as the `value`. As Jean-François Fabre stated, the `*` just unpacks your tuple into positional arguments